# QT Creator https request not working on VM

Tags: c++, https, request, virtual-machine, qt-creator

I am working on a small Application in Qt with C++.
(This Application is meant to run on Windows)
I am sending a few https requests in this App and recieving answers from an API.
This works fine. But on Vm with Windows 10 Enterprise 21H1 Image I cant get a connection to the Api. Installing Open SSL on the VM is not an option.
What else could I do, to get it working on the VM?

Comment: Does the rest of your VM's apps have access to the Internet? This sounds like it can possibly be that your VM doesn't have internet access.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Qt creator (which is just an IDE).

Comment: It has connection to the internet, that is not the problem..